# Arch linux not booting in QEMU

Tags: boot, grub, arch-linux, qemu

I am using QEMU to install arch linux on a 5G raw img disk and everytime and install it and reboot it boots back into arch but when i close qemu and try boot back into arch i am not prompted with the grub boot but it says WARN: No MBR magic, treating disk as raw. Booting... So i am assuming its only using the RAM and not actually writing anything to the drive. I also thought it was the disk type i was using as i was using qcow2 at first but got the same error so i switched to raw and im still getting the same error. It will say booing and do nothing else forever

This is my command to start QEMU:

```
.\qemu-system-x86_64 -drive file=archlinux.img,index=0,media=disk,format=raw -cdrom archlinux.iso -m 3G -snapshot -cpu core2duo -smp 2
```

I am installing arch following this tutorial:

```
https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/install-arch-linux-on-virtualbox/
```

I am not sure if im installing grub properly or not ive just been following the tutorial

Comment: I tried booting with another disk which is qcow2 that i jsut created and it has nothing on it and i got same error i think it is because nothing is actually being writen even though arch says that is has been written when i format the disk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have added the "-snapshot" option to your qemu command line, so this is expected behavior:

According to the manual, the -snapshot option instructs qemu to...

> Write to temporary files instead of disk image files. In this case,
>   the raw disk image you use is not written back. You can however force
>   the write back by pressing C-a s.